# Two non-isomorphic modules that are isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Can you give me a *concrete* example of two modules over a ring $R$ that are not isomorphic , but that are isomorphic as abelian groups.

I know that this question was posted here before, but the answer given was not a concrete example and I would like to see one.

Comment: Could you post a link to the question you mentioned, please? Also, it would be helpful if you could specify what you mean by "concrete" example...

Comment: @A.P. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245158/isomorphic-abelian-groups-which-are-not-isomorphic-r-modules

Comment: I mean an example of modules

Comment: Andrew's answer from that question seems very concrete to me...

Comment: @A.P. But I never had dual numbers over a field

Comment: Ok, then what is wrong with Mariano's answer? He says that "$\Bbb{R}$ is an infinite dimensional $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, so a direct sum of finitely many copies (or countabl[y] many) of $\Bbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ as a $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, and therefore as an abelian group." Surely you've seen the fields of real and rational numbers in your studies?

Comment: @A.P. But why arent they isomorphic as modules?

Comment: They aren't isomorphic as $\Bbb{R}$-vector spaces, i.e. modules, since a module over a field is a vector space...

Comment: Do you know what the trivial $R$-module over the group $G$ is? Then let $(R,G)$ be your favourite nontrivial module. The two have isomorphic underlying groups but are not isomorphic as modules.

Comment: @TonyStrong, I just added another answer to the question you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=KG$ with $K$ a field (with char $K \ne 2$) and $G$ cyclic of order two, and let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the trivial and nontrivial $1$-dimensional (over $K$) $KG$-modules. So, in $M_2$, $G$ acts by multiplying by $-1$.

Comment: Can you also explain why they arent isomorphic as modules, but they are as abelian groups?

Comment: This feels *a lot* like a joke... :)

Comment: @A.P. why does this feel like a joke?

Comment: Because in the comments the OP said that he's never seen dual numbers, and in your answer you are using modules over a group algebra.